# set the height of a container to hold dynamically-sized widget

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here's an example:  http://la.truxmap.com/marker?id=thesweetstruck&t=1267058348000

The widget on the right usually overflows unless i set the height of the container to some fixed size like 1800px.  What I want to do is have the div with the white background (container) always span AT LEAST until the bottom of the widget.  I don't want to use overflow because I dont want anything hidden and i certainly dont want scroll bars.

Is there a css solution to this?  I feel like ive tried most everything except writing a javascript solution, which i would like to avoid because im still very much an amateur with javascript.  Thanks so much!

Edit:

I don't have any requirements as to how this can be done, id just like a solution.  ive been trying to figure out this problem for over a week and its now driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to clear your floats. After this div

```
<div id="truckLogo">...bunch of stuff...</div>
```

Add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to fix it.  Should the height of the container div be set to something special?  Is this type of issue typically something can be address with css?

Comment: It looks like it is either different than last time I looked at it or I wrote down the wrong id. Get rid of all that min-height stuff and add clear:both to this div <div style="position: relative; padding: 4px;"></div>

Comment: ahh yes.  sorry, what happens is the page is created dynamically and the original link i posted no longer exists, so it forwards you to a different, similar looking page.

Comment: i am having the same problem on that other page as well though, so i am trying to get your solution to work right now